# How to deploy flask-socketio app to Google Cloud Platform App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, flask-socketio

I coded a flask-socketio app that serves data to a website via websockets.

My directory structure is like this:

- main.py
- website

  - index.html
  - main.js
  - style.css

My app.yaml is like this:

```
runtime: python38

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: website/index.html
    upload: website/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: website

entrypoint: python main.py
```

I ran gcloud app deploy in the directory and managed to deploy the website to GCP. It is now available under https://codevis.ew.r.appspot.com/

However, the flask-socketio app isn´t running and I can´t connect to it with the website.

My main.py deploys the flask-socketio app like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

[...]

def run_app():
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_app()
```

In my main.js, I am trying to connect to flask-socketio like this:

```
var socket = io.connect("https://codevis.ew.r.appspot.com:5000");
```

When testing the flask-socketio locally (using var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");), everything works perfectly. I just can´t get GCP App Engine to actually run the flask-socketio app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine standard doesn't support websockets. You can do it on [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity), but you can't scale to 0 (and that implies extra cost)

For a scale to 0 platform, you can consider Cloud Run which will be able to accept be directional websockets soon.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35886348) existing for the implementation of this feature.

You may *star* it so that it gains visibility and also include your email in the *CC* section in order to receive further updates on this. However, please keep in mind that as it is a Feature Request there is no ETA available for the implementation at this time.